# Does Google Cloud Vision API (Web Detection) limit # of matching images and web entities?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vision-api

I'm using Google Cloud Vision API (the [Web Detection API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-web#vision_web_detection_gcs-ruby) part) for the first time.

I issued several requests for different images, and found that it always shows me at most 10 pages with matching images, and 10 web entities. This is using the Python code exactly as shown on the documentation page linked above, to print out the matching page URLs and web entities.

Is this a tacit limit on the Web Detection API? There's no mention of this in the documentation that I could find, but it seems like a weird coincidence if every image I tried so far has at most 10 of the above.

I was hoping to use popularity of the image (as computed by # of matching page urls from around the web) as a signal, which is why understanding if this limit exists is important.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello! Have you prepared any code and can you share it with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google documentation that you mentioned, there is a "max_results" variable in the example, for example here in Ruby but also in the REST API sample:

[image: ruby sample]

It looks like what you are looking for.

But I confirm that the documentation is not clear about what would be the max possible value for example.

Comment: Is it possible to filter any specific domain? Say for example, I like to get URLs of all the similar images from gettyimages.com